# lightswitch how to suppress the "Save changes before closing" message when no new data entered

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a default data entry screen in Lightswitch.  Problem is, when the user does not wish to enter a new record, the user closes the screen to navigate elsewhere.  Upon closing the form, the user is presented with the "Save changes before closing?" message.  Is there a way I can suppress this message in a scenario in which the user has not entered any data in this screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the screen's *Closing* method, you can add a call to *DiscardChanges* for the entity that the screen is bound to (which I've called *EntityPropertyName* in the code below).

**VB:**

```
Me.EntityPropertyName.Details.DiscardChanges
```

**C#:**

```
this.EntityPropertyName.Details.DiscardChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks Yann. This put me on the right track to find that the line is actually "this.EntityPropertyName.Details.DiscardChanges();"

Comment: Oh, so it is, sorry about that.